# Nested JSON Objects

Tags: json, delphi, pascal

I am using an API to output a JSON file as such, and so cannot edit the format of the JSON file. Is there any way to be able to iterate through each intraday date, to find the value of open in each date?

I have tried using `Object.intraday[0].open` however this does not seem to work, as the it is not contained within an array? 
I realise that I can use `Object.intraday.date.open` (where date is e.g "2018-10-19 15:59:00:"); however I want to be able to index to the different times.

```
{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "stock_exchange_short": "NASDAQ",
    "timezone_name": "America/New_York",
    "intraday": {
        "2018-10-19 15:59:00:" {
            "open": "219.49",
            "close": "219.23",
            "high": "219.61",
            "low": "219.19",
            "volume": "302415"
        },
        "2018-10-19 15:58:00:" {
            "open": "219.62",
            "close": "219.48",
            "high": "219.70",
            "low": "219.48",
            "volume": "173762"
        },
             ....
```

This is the pascal code that I am using in order to do this, using a test JSON of `{"intraday":{"2018-10-1915:59:00":{"open":"23","low":"4"},"2018-10-1915:58:00":{"open":"25","low":"21"}}}`

```
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"intraday":{"2018-10-1915:59:00":{"open":"23","low":"4"},"2018-10-1915:58:00":{"open":"25","low":"21"}}}');
  j:=0;
  begin
    if JSONVAlue is TJSONObject then
      begin
          // Get the quote and low values
          quote := JSONValue.GetValue<string>('intraday[0]');
          low := JSONValue.GetValue<string>('intraday.low');
          Memo1.Lines.Add(quote + ': ' + low);
          j := j+1;
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Json Parser](https://github.com/thomaserlang/delphi-json) and this [question](https://github.com/thomaserlang/delphi-json/issues/9). Also make `intraday` an array.

Comment: Also here's a [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/RTL.JSONWriter) on how it should look like and to do it.

Comment: @AdriaanBoshoff I can't modify the JSON file, as it is taken from an API. Is there any way of maybe iterating through the different intraday times to find their corresponding "open" value for example?

Comment: `intraday` is a single object with nested objects that use dates as their field names. That is a weird design choice. It would have made more sense for `intraday` to be an array of objects that have their dates as string fields. Whoever designed this API doesn't understand JSON and OOP very well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree, but unfortunately there was very limited choice for a free, live stock database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
procedure TfmMain.ParseIntraDay(AMemo: TMemo);
var
  LObject, LIntraDayObj: TJSONObject;
  LEnumerator: TJsonPairEnumerator;
  LQuote, LLow: String;
begin
  LObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('{"intraday":{"2018-10-19 15:59:00":{"open":"23","low":"4"},"2018-10-19 15:58:00":{"open":"25","low":"21"}}}') as TJSONObject;
  try
    LIntraDayObj := LObject.GetValue('intraday') as TJSONObject; //{"2018-10-19 15:59:00":{"open":"23","low":"4"},"2018-10-19 15:58:00":{"open":"25","low":"21"}}
    LEnumerator := LIntraDayObj.GetEnumerator;
    while LEnumerator.MoveNext do
    begin
      LQuote := LEnumerator.Current.JsonString.Value;
      LLow := (LEnumerator.Current.JsonValue As TJsonObject).Values['low'].Value;
      AMemo.Lines.Add(String.Format('%s: %s', [LQuote, LLow]));
    end;
   finally
     LObject.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Should give the following output in the memo:

```
2018-10-19 15:59:00: 4
2018-10-19 15:58:00: 21
```

Youcan use this as a basis for what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Didn't know about the getEnumerator function, good to know. So is this function just used to index the intraday values?

Comment: @Test1234 it is one way to do it, but it is not the only way. You could use the [`TJSONObject.Pairs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Pairs) property instead. But, if you are going to use the enumerator, you should use the friendlier [`for...in`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements) loop syntax instead.